# Friendly_id scope issue. Numeric slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, friendly-id

I'm trying to use Friendly ID to create more custom urls. However, the column I want to use for a slug is still a number. I don't want to create a separate column just for the slug, since it would be identical.

I have a *Lot* that belongs to an *Auction*.
*Auctions* have many *Lots* (items for sale).

A *Lot* has a `lot_number`, which is unique to an *Auction*. It's not unique throughout the entire table, though. It's basically just a way to order the lots in each auction.

My URLs look like: /auctions/1/lots/21 (/auctions/:auction_id/lots/:id)
I want them to be: /auctions/1/lots/1 (/auctions/:auction_id/lots/:lot_number)

I added the following to **lot.rb**:

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :lot_number
```

It almost works. It shows me a Lot with the correct lot number, but the wrong auction.
I read about scopes on the Friendly ID docs, which sounded perfect. I could scope the lot against the auction...
So I tried:

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :lot_number, :use => :scoped, :scope => :auction_id
```

Now I see the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: lots.slug: SELECT  "lots".* FROM "lots"  WHERE "lots"."slug" = '1' LIMIT 1
```

Why is the SQL `WHERE lots.slug = 1`? Shouldn't it be `WHERE lots.auction_id = 1`?
Am I using the wrong syntax? Not sure where I've gone wrong.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that you should have a look at `from_param` and `to_param` methods that are used in rails to lookup models: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/to_param